# How do you parameterize a Meteor server publication with client provided criteria and subscribe to it properly?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a 'Tastings' collection of objects each containing a 'when' Date property.  I would like to publish a few different views of these objects. I have added the following to my lib/publications.js source.

```
Meteor.publish('pastTastings', function(now) {
  check(now, Date);
  return Tastings.find({when: {'$lt': now}}, {sort: {when: -1}});
};
Meteor.publish('futureTastings', function(now) {
  check(now, Date);
  return Tastings.find({when: {'$gte': now}}, {sort: {when: 1}});
};
```

I am using Iron Router and have set up the following routes in my lib/router.js source:

```
Router.route('/past', {
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('pastTastings', new Date());
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      tastings: Tastings.find({when: {'$lt': new Date()}}, {sort: {when: -1}});
    };
  }
});
Router.route('/future', {
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('futureTastings', new Date());
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      tastings: Tastings.find({when: {'$gte': new Date()}}, {sort: {when: 1}});
    };
  }
});
```

In my templates, I'm referencing the 'tastings' property of the object returned from the 'data' function, but the page continues to load as if the subscription or the client-side Tastings query is failing.

Am I misunderstanding how Iron Router and Meteor publish/subscribe work together?  If so, what is the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm seeing is an issue with the syntax for IR's data method. Try returning an object directly from it:

```
Router.route('/past', {
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('pastTastings', new Date());
  },
  data: {
    tastings: function(){ return Tastings.find(); }
  }
});
```

Or if you will only have this one data set, you can do `data: function() { return Tastings.find(); }`.